# Using barplot in R doesn't not match the data?

Tags: r, plot

I want to use `barplot` (or any other better options) to plot the following data:

```
   action_number times
1              1 13408
2              2  5550
3              3  2757
4              4  1782
5              5  1114
6              6   847
7              7   582
8              8   410
9              9   306
10            10   278
11            11   212
12            12   165
13            13   139
14            14   112
15            15   106
16            16    82
17            17    64
18            18    61
19            19    69
20            20    47
21            21    31
22            22    40
23            23    34
24            24    31
25            25    28
26            26    26
27            27    21
28            28    16
29            29    14
30            30    16
31            31    11
32            32    10
33            33    11
34            34    10
35            35     4
36            36     6
37            37     5
38            38     8
39            39     6
40            40     3
41            41     6
42            42     8
43            43     3
44            44     3
45            45     7
46            46     8
47            47     4
48            48     4
49            49     1
50            50     4
51            51     2
52            52     4
53            53     3
54            54     1
55            55     2
56            56     1
57            58     2
58            59     4
59            60     1
60            62     2
61            63     1
62            66     1
63            67     4
64            68     2
65            69     1
66            70     1
67            71     1
68            73     1
69            74     1
70            77     1
71            79     1
72            80     1
73            82     1
74            92     2
75            97     1
76            98     1
77           103     1
78           106     1
79           114     1
80           118     1
81           128     1
82           142     1
83           148     1
84           153     1
85           155     1
86           166     1
87           183     1
88           218     1
89           224     1
90           298     1
91           536     1
```

I am using the following, but it does not match the data correctly:

```
mp <- barplot(data$times,axes=FALSE,ylim=c(0,13408))
axis(1,at=data$action_number,labels=data$action_number)  
#??? Should I use at=data$action_number to at=data$times
axis(2,seq(0,91,3),c(0:30))
```

![enter image description here][1]
Problems:
- the x-axis does not have 536, it only goes to 224
- the Y axis only shows one number

Can you please give me advice and if I should use any package?

Comment: are `x` and `y` numeric? or factor? can u paste `dput` output here?

Comment: yeah I am trying to have a bar plot with x axis as action number and y as times They dont let me add image (i should have 10 or more reputation)

Comment: @goodone - post a link to imgur.com or somewhere similar where you can host an image. If it adds to the question it can then be edited in.

Comment: what is the output of `class(data$times)` and `class(data$action_number)`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/LOnM1lr.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7zRbDhF.png

Comment: @Ananta Times is the name of second column and action_number if the name of first Column

Answer (score 0):

still, unclear but may be something like this

```
barplot(data$times, xlab=data$action_number)
mp <- barplot(data$times,axes=FALSE,ylim=c(0,13408))
axis(1,at=seq(1,91,10),labels=data$action_number[seq(1,91,10)])  
axis(2,seq(0,13408,500),seq(0,13408,500))
```